# OpenIdConnect HTTP Basic authentication scheme for client authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I'm trying to implement an OpenIdConnect login to my .net core 2.0 site.
The IdentityServer I'm trying to use only supports 'client_secret_basic' as token_endpoint_auth_methods. 
I configured the application as follows:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
       .AddCookie()
       .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
       {
           options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
           options.Authority = Auhtority;
           options.ClientId = ClientID;
           options.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
           options.ResponseType = "code";
           options.SaveTokens = true;
           options.Scope.Add("profile");
           options.Scope.Add("rrn");
       });
```

But this seems to post the ClientId and ClientSecret to the body of the request and not using HTTP Basic authentication.
I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find how to configure the OpenIdConnect to use client_secret_basic instead of client_secret_post. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated: your options.DefaultChallengeScheme should be OpenIdConnect.

Comment: There's no support for alternative auth methods for the token endpoint. You can use the AuthorizationCodeReceived event to redeem the code yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks, any samples available on how to redeem the code?

Comment: I have a small example which uses Azure AD: https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth/blob/master/Core2AadAuth/Startup.cs#L69. It uses the AAD libraries to get tokens, but the general approach using `HandleCodeRedemption(accessToken, idToken)` after getting tokens is the same.

Comment: Here's one that shows how to use that event, but it doesn't cover that flow. You'll need to use HttpClient to send your own request. https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/2697b0c9c46294ee499621f0d6fc60489d1b31ac/samples/OpenIdConnect.AzureAdSample/Startup.cs#L62

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I use the tokenclient from IdentityModel to RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I finally got it to work using the following options / event hook `using System.Net.Http;`:

```
options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
        {
            context.Backchannel.SetBasicAuthenticationOAuth(context.TokenEndpointRequest.ClientId, context.TokenEndpointRequest.ClientSecret);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
```

I got this mostly out of the comments to your question and with the method mentioned there being marked as deprecated with a hint to the new extension method I use.

Note: SetBasicAuthenticationOAuth is an extension on HttpClient from the IdentityModel nuget

Comment: You just saved my day! Thank you!

Comment: You also need to remove `client_id`/`client_secret` from request body (From [rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.3): _The client MUST NOT use more than one authentication method in each request._).  Just set them to `null` in `context.TokenEnpointRequest`.

Comment: Do you know what to use in 2022? 
context.Backchannel doesn't seem to have the method SetBasicAuthenticationOAuth now.

Comment: **SetBasicAuthenticationOAuth**  is an extension on HttpClient from the **IdentityModel nuget** package. Just install it and add the namespace "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect"

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 you still can use the IdentityModel nuget.
It has some System.Net.Http extension methods.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/blob/6f9e050167846724828138ba6ee8b626eb31c669/src/Client/BasicAuthenticationOAuthHeaderValue.cs

Keep in mind you have to remove the  client_id/client_secret from the TokenEndpointRequest object.